# How to make Agile metrics useful to stakeholders and project managers

Tags: agile, kanban, metrics

I have started using Actionable Agile lately. This tool is essentially used for Agile Metrics e.g. Cycle time, throughput, monte-carlo predictability etc.

Does anyone know how I can translate this data into something that is useful for project managers and stakeholders that don't necessarily understand Agile metrics.

e.g. I can predict how long it will take to do x number of stories in 30 days - how is this useful for them?

e.g. 2. I can predict at what date the in progress stories will complete - how can I provide this to them on an ongoing basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the metrics that you cite (along with a probability) answer the question "When will this piece of work be done?" When your stakeholders ask that question, you have an answer to give them based on your data.

Don't think of it as providing metrics to stakeholders. In my experiences, they don't care about metrics. They care about how long it will take work to be done, how much it costs, and what the level of quality is. Other stakeholders may have other cares. Metrics should be a fact and history based approach to provide answers to questions that they have.

Comment: OK. Just to clarify, are you saying that it should be pull based? i.e. I shouldn't bother creating any regular reports for them, I should just calculate the answer when they ask for it using the metrics?

Comment: @user32613 If they regularly ask for reports, then it may be good to anticipate. But yes. Generally speaking, you should be addressing their concerns. It's safe to say that stakeholders will want to know about time and cost and quality, so having lightweight measures in place to address those is good. But until you start getting questions that you can't answer, don't put a comprehensive metrics system or reporting structure into place.